# regex oddity - why isn't this working and how to match it?

Tags: php, regex

I'm using PHP 5.6.30 and doing some customised attribute editing on HTML  tags. I have come across an oddity and not sure what to make of it, or how to work around it. It's best shown by a code snippet:

```
$string = '<li><a href="#Interfaces">2 Interfaces</a></li>';

$pattern1 = '/(<a\s+[^>]*? href)/i';
$pattern2 = '/(<a\s+[^>]*?href)/i';
$replace = '[DETECTED: "\1"]';

echo "Using pattern 1: " . preg_replace($pattern1, $replace, $string) . "\n\n";
echo "Using pattern 2: " . preg_replace($pattern2, $replace, $string);
```

output:

```
Using pattern 1: <li><a href="#Interfaces">2 Interfaces</a></li>

Using pattern 2: <li>[DETECTED: "<a href"]="#Interfaces">2 Interfaces</a></li>
```

It also doesn't match against `'%(<a\s+[^>]*?\shref)%im'` (just in case it's space vs whitespace char that's the issue).

Why does `[^>]href` match but `[^>] href` and `[^>]\shref` don't? Logically they should have identical matching, as the space matches any of a [^>] char,  a literal space, or a \s class.

NOTE: I've simplified the regex way down to the actual issue; please don't ask "why RU do it that way", as the snippet isn't intended to show or explain the entire code, just highlight the small part that's unexpectedly failing.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? According to [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/) this should be working. Even with the space.

Comment: Added that info to OP. It's 5.6.30 (that's what's installed on the platform so not much choice), and yes I would expect it should as well..... I've added a full-code example just retested that shows what I'm getting.

Comment: The first rule of using Regex to parse HTML is *not* to use Regex to parse HTML. Seriously. Don’t. There’s [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/de/class.domdocument.php) and [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/de/class.domxpath.php). They’re appropriate for what you need.

Comment: @Daniel_B - I might post a 2nd question based on your excellently helpful answer. It doesnt answer this question, but does help a lot with part of the underlying issue.

Comment: Question [posted](https://superuser.com/questions/1215051/using-domdocument-domxpath-to-remove-all-but-specific-tags-and-attributes-from): If you can post an answer it would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first expression contains two obligatory spaces between `<a` and `href`, but your string has only one

`/(<a\s+[^>]*? href)/i` - `\s+` (one or more whitespace) and  (exatly one space) are both need to match

The second pattern contains only one obligatory space.

Comment: Oh god. It woiuld be something that obvious! Thank you!