# Using DOMDocument + DOMXPath to remove all but specific tags and attributes from HTML

Tags: php, html

I have arbitrary body HTML and need to process it in PHP to remove all tags except a few "well known" ones (**<h1><h2><h3><h4><ul><ol><li><p><br><a><b><u><i><sup><sub><table><th><tr><td><blockquote>** and their closing tags) and all attributes except the **href** attribute of **<a>**, and return any remaining HTML as a string.  I also need to manually remove any hrefs other than `"(https?|ftp)://.*"`, but that would be the only remaining regex work.

I don't need to check the HTML's overall validity, open/closing tag matching etc, the HTML should be trustworthy and this is primarily to remove unwanted tags and attributes, leaving nothing but plain text and a few of the most basic elements.

I started by using strstr() to get the body HTML, then strip_tags() to remove all but the given tags, then regex to remove all attributes except for HREF, and last convert all remaining < to &lt; (other than in known tags) as a final round of input sanitisation. But one comment suggested using DOMDocument and DOMXPath, not regex, for any HTML processing.

It sounds a good idea to be using the right tools, but I can't figure out how to use them.  How can I use these to remove all but these specific elements, and also remove all attributes from all elements except for `href` in , from my HTML string?

**Update:** Its a proposed patch for an existing third party project, and I can't import packages like HTML Purifier if they aren't already there. I have PHP DOM, and a few other PHP extensions, but standard PHP + XML + DOM handling seems to be the toolkit I have available for this.

Comment: A yes. In that case, I would once again recommend a slightly different approach. There is no need to reinvent the wheel! Use [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) and allow only the `href` attribute.

Comment: Its a proposed patch for an existing third party project. I have PHP DOM, and a few other extensions, but not HTML Purifier. Pure PHP and PHP DOM are the only tools I have. Noting that in the question.